# Is GNOME itself considered "software"?

Tags: gnome, terminology

The GNOME project aims to provide the user with a desktop environment, and it does consist of many pieces of software. There indeed is a foundation called the GNOME foundation, and  there is a desktop environment called GNOME, but well, can GNOME itself be called **software**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"GNOME" is four things:

1. A development environment encompassing several desktop features, functions and processes, one example being GTK+.
2. A desktop environment using software based on the development framework.
3. A foundation that supports other software not neccessarily part of either of the first two (although *usually* using GNOME libraries).
4. A little ceramic man, often with a hat, occasionally with a fishing rod or a wheel barrow. A garden ornament.

All of these are collections of software although each has different organisational features and aims. The third is more of an organisational "umbrella" than a discrete set of software but the first two are fairly discrete and yes, could easily be called software. Garden ornaments are rarely thought to be software.

Hearing "GNOME", one would usually infer the person was talking about the desktop environment... But just as people get angry about people not calling Linux "GNU/Linux", they might prefer you to use the longhand.

Comment: One important thing you left out: *GNOME is a project to develop a libre desktop*, just like you can say *Ubuntu is a project to develop a Linux-based distro*.

Comment: @Tshepang I thought that was covered by #2, just with less flowery language.

Comment: Since **1**, **2**, and **3** are all software (and **4** must be a joke: who ever heard of a garden gnome in all capital letters?), I think it would be appropriate to add to this answer that yes, GNOME is certainly *software*, though it would not be right to call it *a program*.

Comment: @EliahKagan To say it is not a program and to call it software doesn't make any sense. Of course its a program. It has a set of instructions correct? Then it's a program. Maybe you are confusing application with program.

Comment: @Matt There is no reasonable sense in which GNOME is a program. The broadest definition of "program" is ["a sequence of instructions written to perform a specified task with a computer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program#cite_note-pis-ch4-p132-0). GNOME contains many such sequences but is not a single such sequence; to say GNOME is a program in that sense is like saying that Firefox 8 and a particular [PCA pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient-controlled_analgesia)'s firmware, considered together, constitute "a program." A box of video games and tshirts isn't a program either.

Comment: @EliahKagan sorry i still don't see your logic. You said that GNOME is a piece of software, yet all software is a program. So i don't see how you can say it's a piece of software and not a program. Yes firefox is software (application software) and firmware is also software which you can consider to be system software. So both are programs. All it is, is a set of instructions. If GNOME has a set of instructions like a function, then it's a program. simple as that.

Comment: @Matt A human is a mammal. A dog is a mammal. A human and dog taken together are two mammals, but they are not "a mammal." All parts of GNOME, taken together, are software, but they do not, taken together, constitute "a program." All programs are software. Not all software is "a program." As an independent point, usually it is most useful to consider a program to be an executable sequence with a *1st instruction* (entry point). Then many "softwares"--including many parts of GNOME--such as the GTK+ *library* are not *programs*. (Only in the broadest sense of "program" is a library a program.)

Answer (score 2):

It would be unusual to refer to the 'GNOME software', but as you say, GNOME consists of many pieces of software, so it wouldn't be wrong to say GNOME is software.

Of course the GNOME Project and the GNOME Foundation are orgnanisations that you wouldn't describe as software.

A similar example: KDE was recently renamed to the *KDE Software Compilation*.

Comment: That's what I'm unsure about. It's just a project that gathers software - i wonder if it makes it itself a piece of software. Do we call The Free Software foundation, or the GNU Project a software? They also consist of many pieces of software, but aren't software itself.

Comment: @rafalcieslak GNU is an *Operating System* (using the Linux Kernel), the two cases aren't *really* comparable.

Comment: The difference is that *The Free Software foundation* doesn't release software in a bundle that's referred to as *The Free Software Foundation"* - however the *GNOME organisation* does release the *GNOME Desktop Environment*.

Comment: This still makes it just an umbrella-project for many pieces of software, that using some references from GNOME project, cooperate and work well together as a desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, for me if it `consists of many pieces of software` (which it does), then I'll be calling it `GNOME Desktop Suite` probably, but yeah, it's hard to define it as just "software".